# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Email Send -Custom Object

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to send email from Exact Target using Custom Object in Salesforce? I tried with Triggered Sends and Send Definition but its always asking for Lead/Contact look up for Email address. In my case I have to send email from custom object having email address as custom field.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found this can work using the send to reports with Salesforce email sends / data extensions if a report can be created with the custom object and a Contact or Lead ID associated with the custom object

[This was a useful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOIV_NdFvhY) in helping me configure this

Comment: thanks for this information. I will look into it. Do you know if we can use custom objects' field in etmc? I want to use salesforce custom fields into email template of etmc.

Comment: If the field is included in the report that is then mapped into the Saleforce data extension within etmc it can be included with a personalization string %%fieldname%%